# Outputting result of one-dimensional array with calculation in C language?

Tags: c

I am a new person on stackoverflow. I have stuck in a problem when I try to make a program with C language that will print out a maximum element in an one-dimensional array by using functions. I decided print out my element in in many ways. I have try to put "printf"  in the "checkmax" fuction, in "main" function and make a function
"printmax" just for print my elements but none of these ways seem like work well.I need some helps.

```
int checkmax(int a[], int n)
{
int max=a[0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
{
    if(a[i]>max) max=a[i];
}
return max;
//printf("max = %d", max);
}

/*void printmax()
{
    if(checkmax(a,n)==max) printf("max = %d", max)
}*/

int main()
{
int n;
printf("Enter number of elements => ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int *a=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
inputarray(a,n);
checkmax(a,n);
//printf("max = %d", max);
getchar(); getchar();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors with the `printf()` function?  If so, make sure that you add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your `.c` file.

Comment: Is the problem that nothing is printed out or that an error occurs?

Comment: Also, if you're going to use the same variables across multiple functions, make sure to make said variables have the file scope.  I.e., put the variables ***outside*** of any function.

Answer (score 0):

You have `i` undeclared in the for loop.
Also this `for(i=0;i<n;i++);` means that you have an empty for loop because of the semicolon at the end. If you fix these you should be fine.

e.g.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(a[i]>max) max=a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors we should address.

First, you are trying to use local variables as global ones.  E.g. trying to use `max` in `printmax()` when it was defined locally in `checkmax()`.

Second, your `for` loop does nothing due to the semicolon at the end.  Also make sure to do `int i = 0` instead of `i = 0`, since `i` was not declared before entering the loop.

Third, if you are getting errors from calling `printf()`, you should make sure that you included `stdio.h` at the top of your file:  `#include <stdio.h>`

(the `printf()` in `checkmax()` also needs to be *before* `return max;`)

**Solution:**

Remove the declaration of `max`, `a`, and `n` in their functions, and instead declare them at the top of your file,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max = 0, n = 0;
int a[] = {0};
...
```

fix the `for` loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ...
}
```

and remove `printmax()`.  The function is useless, since you print `max` in `checkmax()`.